# How to get a value from a list in apache velocity file?

Tags: java, arraylist, velocity

How to get the value from UIRowFormatList in vm file?
I am using the below code for this.

```
#set($i = $velocityCount-1)    
#set($rowFormatComponents = $UIRowFormatList.get($i))
```

I am getting this exception when i run this:

```
"fo:table-body" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (table-row+|table-cell+)
```

When I am hardcoding the value of i as 0 in get method like this, it is displaying proper values:

```
#set($rowFormatComponents = $UIRowFormatList.get(0)
```

Comment: "I am getting an exception" what exception? Maybe you could post a stacktrace

Comment: If the question is how to access an element from a list (say `foo`) when its rank is in another variable (say `i`) the answer is : `$foo[$i]` or `${foo}[${i}]` if you want (or need) to add the curly braces.

Comment: `$velocityCount` is only valid in a `#foreach` loop, are you sure that's the case?

Comment: i have tried the above solution you suggested, its not working for me.:(

Comment: No i dont think so that is is valid inly for foreach loop.Because when i tried printing the value of i ,it is printing correct value.